# Alert Dialog weird trouble on Contextual Action Mode

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, android-alertdialog

I have a very strange situation. I am using Contextual Action Mode for selecting multiple items of the `ListView`. The flow goes as follows:

User selects the list items using long press on them --> Uses the action item "Operations" to choose what he wants to do --> This action item creates a `AlertDialog` with 4 list items (call it **dialog1**)  where the 3rd item calls another `AlertDialog` (call it **dialog2**) which includes an `EditText` for some data input and later calls a method to perform it.

Later the user hits Back button or Home button to exit the Action Mode.
The problem is that **dialog2** shows up alternatively like first time user selects the list items, Chooses "Operations" action item and chooses the 3rd item which calls **dialog2**. Now **dialog2** will appear as it is supposed to. Later the user hits the Back button to quit the Action Mode.
The SECOND TIME user performs the same steps **dialog2** doesn't appear.

The logcat shows this error in both the cases:

> 09-04 10:53:12.096 6299-6299/com.project.pcmanager
>   W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input
>   event receiver has already been disposed.

Some code:

```
     public void sendAction(final Context context, final EventModel model, int position) {

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        String[] operations = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.operations);
        // null set before is modified here
        model.setEventTitle(operations[position]);
        final String ip = model.getEventIP();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                try {
                    object.put("command", "power_off");
                    notifyUser();
                    LogUtils.addEntry(model.toString());
                    execCommand(ip,object);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                try {
                    object.put("command", "reboot");
                    notifyUser();
                    LogUtils.addEntry(model.toString());
                    execCommand(ip,object);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                //Show AlertDialog with EditText on it for command input
                final EditText txtCommand = new EditText(context);

                // Set some properties to EditText
                txtCommand.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
                txtCommand.setMinHeight(150);
                txtCommand.setHint("Ex: ping google.com");
                txtCommand.setSingleLine();

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle("Run a task")
                        .setView(txtCommand)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Run",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        String command = txtCommand.getText().toString();
                                        if (command.length() > 0) {
                                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                                            try {
                                                object.put("run", command);
                                                object.put("ip", ip);
                                                notifyUser();
                                                LogUtils.addEntry(model.toString());
                                                performRemoteExec(object);

                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(context, "Please provide a command first!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).setNeutralButton("Cancel", null).show();

                break;
            case 3:
                notifyUser();
                LogUtils.addEntry(model.toString());
                getScreenshot(ip);
                break;
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

                    //Change the title bar with the items selected
                    mode.setTitle(listView.getCheckedItemCount() + " selected");

                    //select the clicked item
                    adapter.toggleSelection(position);

                }

                /**
                 * Called when action mode is first created.
                 * The menu supplied will be used to generate action buttons for the action mode.
                 * @param mode ActionMode being created
                 * @param menu Menu used to populate action buttons
                 * @return true if the action mode should be created,
                 *          false if entering this mode should be aborted.
                 */
                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    onContextMode = true;
                    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_client_select_main, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                /**
                 * Called to refresh an action mode's action menu whenever it is invalidated.
                 * @return true if the menu or action mode was updated, false otherwise.
                 */
                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    return false;
                }

                /**
                 * Called to report a user click on an action button.
                 * @return true if this callback handled the event,
                 *          false if the standard MenuItem invocation should continue.
                 */
                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                    int id = item.getItemId();

                    if (id == R.id.menu_operations) {
                        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                builder.setItems(R.array.operations, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        SparseBooleanArray selectedIds = adapter.getSelectedIds();
                                        // traverse the array to find chosen clients
                                        for (int i = 0; i < selectedIds.size(); i++) {
                                            if (selectedIds.get(i)) {
                                                ClientModel item = adapter.getItem(i);
                                                String ip = item.getClientIP();
                                                String os = item.getOSType();

                                                // null will be treated soon
                                                EventModel model = new EventModel(ip, null, os);
                                                sendAction(builder.getContext(),model, which);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        builder.show();
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                /**
                 * Called when an action mode is about to be exited and destroyed.
                 */
                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                    onContextMode = false;
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured the problem myself. It turns out the culprit was me using `SparseBooleanArray` to get selected clients and I was wrong.

In my code it was:

```
SparseBooleanArray selectedIds = adapter.getSelectedIds();
```

So, I removed this SparseBooleanArray with a new implementation technique. I used `ArrayList<ClientMode> selectedItems` to store all the selected models in my Adapter class.

Also, I created a simple method called `clearSelections` that calls `selectedItems.clear()` method in it. I call this method at on `onDestroyActionMode` as per my app requirement.

**HOW I FOUND THIS?**
I simply placed a bunch of `System.out.println` statements all around `onCreate` and `sendAction` to find out the culprit.